# Calling a function in main that has an array of structs , and an array of float variables in function parameters

Tags: c

Hello I am trying to write a program where I can enter a certain amount of grades(only between 1-10 grades), for a certain amount of students (only between 1-25 students).The program should work for any number of students as long as they fall under the conditions. If the user tries to enter number that are not in between given conditions, then the program will prompt the user to enter correct values until the user has done so. All in all, that portion of my program seems to be working the way I desired, but now I want to find the average grade for each student depending on how many grades the user is going to enter. I intended on doing this by creating a function called GetAverage.

For the parameters of function GetAverage, I have an array of structures of type info , and a array of floating variables as shown:
`float GetAverage(struct Info fStudent[studVar+1], float funcVar[gradeVar+1])`  .
Hopefully everything inside this function is correct, but I don't know for certain because I'm not entirely sure I know how to call GetAverage in my main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>     
int gradeVar;
int studVar;
struct Info {
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    int age;
    int Exam;
    float Average;
};

float GetAverage(struct Info fStudent[studVar+1], float funcVar[gradeVar+1]) 
{                                                      
    float sum = 0.0; 
    for(int n=0; n <= studVar-1; ++n)
    {
        for(int m=0; m <= gradeVar-1; ++m)
        {  
            sum=sum + funcVar[m+1];  
        }
        fStudent[n+1].Average = (sum/gradeVar);
        //return fStudent[n+1].Average;
    }
}                    

int main() {
    //float GetAverage(struct Info fStudent[studVar+1], float funcVar[gradeVar+1]);
    printf("How many students will you grade (1-25)? ");
    scanf("\n%i", &studVar);
    if (studVar<1 || studVar>25) {
        do{                                                
            printf("Invalid\n");                               
            printf("How many students will you grade (1-25)? ");
            scanf("\n%i", &studVar);
        } while (studVar<1 || studVar>25);
    }

    printf("How many grades will you read per student (1-10)? ");       
    scanf("\n%i", &gradeVar);
    if(gradeVar<1 || gradeVar>10) {
        do{
            printf("Invalid\n");
            printf("How many grades will you read per student (1-10)? ");  
            scanf("\n%i", &gradeVar);                                      
        } while(gradeVar<1 || gradeVar>10);
    }
       
    struct Info *studptr[studVar+1];
    struct Info Student[studVar+1];  
    float studGrades[gradeVar+1];
    
    for(int n=0; n <= studVar-1; ++n)
    {                                      
        studptr[n+1]= &Student[n+1];  
        printf("\nEnter First Name for student %i: ", n+1); 
        scanf("\n%s", studptr[n+1]->firstName);
        printf("Enter Last Name for student %i: ", n+1); 
        scanf("\n%s", studptr[n+1]->lastName);                
        /*printf("Enter age for student %i: ", n+1);
          scanf("\n%i", &studptr[n+1]->age);*/

        for(int m=0; m <= gradeVar-1; ++m) {
            printf("Enter grade %i for student %i: ", m+1, n+1);
            scanf("\n%f",&studGrades[m+1]);
        };
    };

    return 0;
}
```

If anyone can anaylze my program for me and explain how I would call the function GetAverage into my main function, I would really appreciate it. There are a few lines that are commented out, some are like that because I don't need them just yet

Comment: Why do you need `+1` in your array declarations?

Comment: You only have one array of grades, not grades for each student.

Comment: The `return` statement in `getAverage` is commented out. This would be flagged by the compiler with the `-Wall` option [which you should _always_ use] (e.g.): _control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]_ And, the `return` should be at the function bottom. As it is, if uncommented, it would return on the first outer loop iteration.

Comment: Why do you need both `studptr` and `Student` arrays?

Comment: And why do you keep adding 1 all over the place, like `scanf("\n%s", studptr[n+1]->firstName);`?

Comment: I wanted to have  +1 in my array declarations so that student 1 corresponds element 1 in array. So if I wanted to grade 25 students the array elements would be from 0-26. That is also why I have n+1 in  my for loops so that I assign info to element 1 for student 1 instead of element 0 for student 1.

Comment: There are somethings that are commented out because I was getting confused which ultimately lead  me to ask for help.

Comment: Normally, if you have 25 students, the array will be `int students[25]` and the index range would be (e.g.) `for (int i = 0;  i < 25;  ++i)`. But, you're trying to do: `for (int i = 1;  i <= 25; ++i)` and you'd need [as you have] `int students[25 + 1]`. But, I'd like to _discourage_ you from indexing from 1 and having an _unused_ element 0. It's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: @Barmar The reason why I have studptr was because I was attempting to have a pointer in my GetAverage as a parameter, and maybe just have a pointer pointing to another pointer but I didn't know how to be honest.

Comment: regaarding: `scanf("\n%i", &studVar);` and similar statements:  the `%i` input format specifier consumes any leadiing white space and `\n` is white space,  Strongly suggest removing the `\n` from each of the format strings

Comment: OT: regarding:  `scanf("\n%s", studptr[n+1]->firstName);` 1) remove the leading `\n` from the format string.  2) when using the `%s` input format specifier, always include a MAX characters modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer, because this specifier always appends a NUL byte to the input.  This avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `for(int m=0; m <= gradeVar-1; ++m) {
            printf("Enter grade %i for student %i: ", m+1, n+1);
            scanf("\n%f",&studGrades[m+1]);`  this only inputs 1 grade per student, not what you want

Comment: OT:  regarding: `float sum = 0.0; `  0.0 is a double literal,,  TO obtain a float literal append a `f` to the end of the literal,  Similar to: `float sum = 0.0f;

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the top comments above, you really don't want to index from 1.

You don't want a separate array for grades. You want the grades array in the student struct.

Since you have defined maximums for number of students and grades, you can take advantage of that.

Also, you can have a function that takes in the student and grade counts.

Here's a refactored version that simplifies the code and puts the grades in the per-student struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXSTUD     25
#define MAXGRADE    10

int gradeVar;
int studVar;

struct Info {
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    int age;
    int Exam;
    float grades[MAXGRADE];
    float Average;
};

float
GetAverage(struct Info *stud)
{
    float sum = 0.0;

    for (int m = 0; m < gradeVar; ++m)
        sum += stud->grades[m];

    sum /= gradeVar;

    return sum;
}

int
asknum(const char *prompt,int lo,int hi)
{
    int val = -1;

    while (1) {
        printf("%s (%d-%d)? ",prompt,lo,hi);
        fflush(stdout);

        scanf("%i", &val);

        if ((val >= lo) && (val <= hi))
            break;

        printf("Invalid\n");
    }

    return val;
}

int
main(void)
{
// NOTE/BUG: don't have a function declaration for something defined above and
// avoid function scoped declarations -- if you _need_ one, put it at file
// scope
#if 0
    // float GetAverage(struct Info fStudent[studVar+1], float funcVar[gradeVar+1]);
#endif

    studVar = asknum("How many students will you grade",1,MAXSTUD);
    gradeVar = asknum("How many grades will you read per student",1,MAXGRADE);

    struct Info Student[studVar];
    //float studGrades[gradeVar];

    struct Info *stud;
    float avg = 0.0;
    for (int n = 0; n < studVar; ++n) {
        stud = &Student[n];

        printf("\nEnter First Name for student %i: ", n + 1);
        scanf("%s", stud->firstName);

        printf("Enter Last Name for student %i: ", n + 1);
        scanf("%s", stud->lastName);

#if 0
        printf("Enter age for student %i: ", n+1);
        scanf("%i", &stud->age);
#endif

        for (int m = 0; m < gradeVar; ++m) {
            printf("Enter grade %i for student %i: ", m + 1, n + 1);
            scanf("%f", &stud->grades[m]);
        }

        stud->Average = GetAverage(stud);
        avg += stud->Average;
        printf("Average: %f\n",stud->Average);
    }

    avg /= studVar;
    printf("Overall average: %f\n",avg);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You only have one array of grades, not an array for each student. So `GetAverage()` can't compute every student's average, it can only compute one average at a time, and doesn't need to receive the `Students` array as an argument. Just pass the array of grades, return the average, and assign it to `Student[n].Average` in the caller.

There's also no need for both `Student` and `studptr` arrays; if you ever need a pointer to a particular student, you can use `&Student[n]`.

I've also cleaned up all your uses of `+1` and `-1` in the array sizes and indexes. The only place where you need to add 1 is in the prompts, since it's common to count from 1 in the user interface. But array indexes go from 0 to length-1.

```
#include <stdio.h>     
int gradeVar;
int studVar;
struct Info {
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    int age;
    int Exam;
    float Average;
};

float GetAverage(float funcVar[gradeVar])
{                                                      
    float sum = 0.0; 
    for(int m=0; m < gradeVar; ++m)
    {
        sum=sum + funcVar[m];
    }
    return sum/gradeVar;
}                    

int main() {
    printf("How many students will you grade (1-25)? ");
    scanf("\n%i", &studVar);
    if (studVar<1 || studVar>25) {
        do{                                                
            printf("Invalid\n");                               
            printf("How many students will you grade (1-25)? ");
            scanf("\n%i", &studVar);
        } while (studVar<1 || studVar>25);
    }

    printf("How many grades will you read per student (1-10)? ");       
    scanf("\n%i", &gradeVar);
    if(gradeVar<1 || gradeVar>10) {
        do{
            printf("Invalid\n");
            printf("How many grades will you read per student (1-10)? ");  
            scanf("\n%i", &gradeVar);                                      
        } while(gradeVar<1 || gradeVar>10);
    }
       
    struct Info Student[studVar];  
    float studGrades[gradeVar];
    
    for(int n=0; n < studVar; ++n)
    {                                      
        printf("\nEnter First Name for student %i: ", n+1); 
        scanf("\n%s", Student[n].firstName);
        printf("Enter Last Name for student %i: ", n+1); 
        scanf("\n%s", Student[n].lastName);                
        printf("Enter age for student %i: ", n+1);
        scanf("\n%i", &Student[n].age);

        for(int m=0; m < gradeVar; ++m) {
            printf("Enter grade %i for student %i: ", m+1, n+1);
            scanf("\n%f",&studGrades[m]);
        };
        Student[n].Average = GetAverage(studGrades);
    };

    return 0;
}
```